# Asynchronous api calls with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am following [redux-saga documentation](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html) on helpers, and so far it seems pretty straight forward, however I stumbled upon an issue when it comes to performing an api call (as you will see link to the docs points to such example)

There is a part `Api.fetchUser` that is not explained, thus I don't quiet understand if that is something we need to handle with libraries like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)? or is that something else. And are saga effects like `call, put` etc.. equivalents of `get, post`? if so, why are they named that way? Essentially I am trying to figure out a correct way to perform a simple post call to my api at url `example.com/sessions` and pass it data like `{ email: 'email', password: 'password' }`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Api.fetchUser` is a function, where should be performed api ajax call and it should return promise.

In your case, this promise should resolve user data variable.

For example:

```
// services/api.js
export function fetchUser(userId) {
  // `axios` function returns promise, you can use any ajax lib, which can
  // return promise, or wrap in promise ajax call
  return axios.get('/api/user/' + userId);
};
```

Then is sagas:

```
function* fetchUserSaga(action) {
  // `call` function accepts rest arguments, which will be passed to `api.fetchUser` function.
  // Instructing middleware to call promise, it resolved value will be assigned to `userData` variable
  const userData = yield call(api.fetchUser, action.userId);
  // Instructing middleware to dispatch corresponding action.
  yield put({
    type: 'FETCH_USER_SUCCESS',
    userData
  });
}
```

`call`, `put` are effects creators functions. They not have something familiar with `GET` or `POST` requests.

`call` function is used to create effect description, which instructs middleware to call the promise.
`put` function creates effect, in which instructs middleware to dispatch an action to the store.

Comment: Remember errorhandeling

try{
  const userData= .....yield...
}catch (e) {
  yield put({
    type: 'FETCH_USER_FAILED'
  });
}

Answer (score 6):

Things like `call`, `put`, `take`, `race` are effects creator functions. The `Api.fetchUser` is a placeholder for your own function that handles API requests.

Here’s a full example of a loginSaga:

```
export function* loginUserSaga() {
  while (true) {
    const watcher = yield race({
      loginUser: take(USER_LOGIN),
      stop: take(LOCATION_CHANGE),
    });

    if (watcher.stop) break;

    const {loginUser} = watcher || {};
    const {username, password} = loginUser || {};
    const data = {username, password};

    const login = yield call(SessionService.login, data);

    if (login.err === undefined || login.err === null && login.response) {
      yield put(loginSuccess(login.response));
    } else {
      yield put(loginError({message: 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.'}));
    }
  }
}
```

In this snippet, the `SessionService` is a class that implements a `login` method which handles the HTTP request to the API. The redux-saga `call` will call this method and apply the data parameter to it. In the snippet above, we can then evaluate the result of the call and dispatch `loginSuccess` or `loginError` actions accordingly using `put`.

A side note: The snippet above is a loginSaga that continuously listens for the `USER_LOGIN` event, but breaks when a `LOCATION_CHANGE` happens. This is thanks to the `race` effect creator.